# I want to apply Mann-Kendall test to NDVI of Sentinel 2 data in R

Tags: r, remote-sensing, ndvi, statistics

I have 20 Sentinel 2 satellite scenes from 2017 to 2020 with the months from May to September to cover the growing season. I calculated the NDVI of each scene and intersected it with my area of interest.

Initially I had checked each of the data for statistical significance using a paired t-test, but quickly found that I was getting significances where they made little sense for the application. After a little research, I came across the Mann-Kendall test to check trends for statistical significance.  My code looks like this so far:

```
library(raster)
library(Kendall)

tif_folder <- "C:/Users/x/Desktop/Data/NDVI/"

ndvi_files <- list.files(path = tif_folder, pattern = "^NDVI.*\\.tif$", full.names = TRUE)

ndvi_stack <- stack(ndvi_files)


function_kendall <- function(x){ return(unlist(MannKendall(x)))}
kendall_result <- calc(ndvi_stack,function_kendall)
print(kendall_result)
```

I get the following error message hundreds of times:

```
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
```

I think this is because my area of interest is not perfectly rectangular and therefore I have some NA values. So my first question would be: Is this because of the NA values and if so, how can I work around this?

**Edit**: The code provided by Spacedman works with RasterStacks that contain NA values and keeps them as NA in the resulting layer as well.

Comment: You can do this via the `raster.kendall` function in spatialEco. However, please note that one assumption of a standard Mann-Kendall test is that the timeseries is not autocorrelated. Since this is rarely the case pre-whitening  is required to account for the serial correlation. The said function does have an option of this, as of the newest CRAN version however, I have been having notable issues with processing times and have not yet addressed ways to speed up processing. At a 10m scale this may very much be an impediment. Perhaps, try a subsample first.

Comment: I have R version 4.3.1, which is the latest. How can I perform prewhitening using raster.kendall? When I execute the following code:

`terra_stack <- rast(ndvi_stack)
k <- raster.kendall(terra_stack, p.value=TRUE, z.value=TRUE,
intercept=TRUE, confidence=TRUE,
tau=TRUE)`
I get the following error message:
`Error: [app] cannot use this function
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...): unused argument (z.value = TRUE)"`
After removing the z.value I still get:
`Error in kendall(y) : The Kendall Tau should have at least 6 observations`
Even though I have 20 scenes.

Comment: If the original question was answered, please add a new question instead of edit the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these warnings/errors are caused, or at least *can be* caused, by missing values. You can replicate this by testing with some missing value vectors:

Ten numbers works fine:

```
> MannKendall(runif(10))
tau = -0.289, 2-sided pvalue =0.28313
```

5 missing from 10 is ok:

```
> MannKendall(c(rep(NA,5),runif(5)))
tau = -0.4, 2-sided pvalue =0.46243
```

But only 3 or 2 values generates fault code 12:

```
> MannKendall(c(rep(NA,7),runif(3)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
tau = -0.333, 2-sided pvalue =1
> MannKendall(c(rep(NA,8),runif(2)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
tau = -1, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

And one or 0 values gets fault code 10:

```
> MannKendall(c(rep(NA,9),runif(1)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =1
> MannKendall(c(rep(NA,10),runif(0)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

Notice these are not R warnings or errors, they are printed messages from the code, and don't stop R returning a value:

```
> z = MannKendall(c(rep(NA,10),runif(0)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
> 
> z
tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

so when this happens in your stack you will still get returned values. What you might want to do is to count the NA values in your source stack, and use that to set the values in your result stack to NA where you only have a few non-NA values in the input. Or possibly the returned values when these faults occur are sufficient to identify that an error occurred at that pixel. For two values you get the `varS` as `NaN`:

```
> unlist(MannKendall(c(1,2,rep(NA,10))))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
 tau   sl    S    D varS 
   1    1    1    1  NaN
```

But for only 3 values you get a fault message but a complete return value set:

```
> unlist(MannKendall(c(1,2,3,rep(NA,10))))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
     tau       sl        S        D     varS 
1.000000 1.000000 3.000000 3.000000 3.666667
```

For all NA values you get this:

```
> unlist(MannKendall(rep(NA,10)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
 tau   sl    S    D varS 
   1    1    0    0    0
```

But this is indistinguishable from a set of identical values, apart from the fault code (which isn't easy to get, and looks like it requires capturing the printed output which is a bit nasty...):

```
> unlist(MannKendall(rep(0,10)))
WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  12
 tau   sl    S    D varS 
   1    1    0    0    0
```

So maybe counting NA values in the source stack is a better idea after all.

Ideally the code which sounds quite old judging by the nature of the error messages and the way it works could maybe do with a rewrite to better signify error and warning situations via return values.

Another way would be to check the number of non-NA in `x` inside your `function_kendall` code and return a list like a valid one but with all `NA` values if there's less than 3 non-missing values. Something like:

```
fk = function(x){
 if(sum(!is.na(x))>3){
   return(unlist(MannKendall(x)))
 }else{
   return(c(tau=NA,sl=NA, S=NA, D=NA, varS=NA))
 }
 } # untested
```

Comment: The examples helped me understand the code and error messages. My raster data each has 475,580 pixels with 226,659 NA values. When I applied my code, I did get results, but all NA values became either 0 or 1, depending on the layer. I applied your last code, did not receive any error messages, and found that, as desired, all NA values remained as NA in the output layer. How is that possible if the code is only checking if there are more than 3 values? Additionally, I am wondering if I can use the Mann-Kendall test with monthly values, or if I need a different test.